# XSLT 1.0 - How to define a template match with a test clause to compare it to a parameter value

Tags: xslt

Well, I can't seem to solve this XSLT 1.0 take-home quiz problem.  Here's the source XML...

```
<College>

    <Class>
        <History>
            <StudentName>Veronica</StudentName>
        </History>
    </Class>

    <Class>
        <History>
            <StudentName>Jasmine</StudentName>
        </History>
    </Class>

    <Class>
        <History>
            <StudentName>Rebecca</StudentName>
        </History>
    </Class>

</College>
```

I'm trying to come up with an XSLT 1.0 to add a new element "AddThis" to the third "History" node using a parameter to denote which "History" node to add "AddThis" to like below...

```
<College>

    <Class>
        <History>
            <StudentName>Veronica</StudentName>
        </History>
    </Class>

    <Class>
        <History>
            <StudentName>Jasmine</StudentName>
        </History>
    </Class>

    <Class>
        <History>
            <StudentName>Rebecca</StudentName>
            <AddThis>Ok</AddThis>
        </History>
    </Class>

</College>
```

Thank you very much for taking the time to read this question.

EDIT: I had to correct the location of the new element "AddThis" inside the "History" node instead of outside of the "History" node, sorry.

Comment: Good question, +1. A simpler solution exists, that doesn't need to use `count()` and the `preceding::` axis.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev, sorry, the "AddThis" element was suppose to be added inside the third "History" node, not outside the third "History" node, my bad.  I corrected this in my question post.  How would I edit your XSLT 1.0 to correct this?  Thanks.

Comment: @_Bug Spray: I have update (look at the very end of) my answer so that the solution now produces your latest desired output. In the future, please, ask new questions, don't change the same question.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev, thank you very much and from now on, I'll ask a new question instead of changing the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pNum" select="3"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Class[History]">
  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="not(position() = $pNum)">
     <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      <AddThis>Ok</AddThis>
    </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<College>
    <Class>
        <History>
            <StudentName>Veronica</StudentName>
        </History>
    </Class>
    <Class>
        <History>
            <StudentName>Jasmine</StudentName>
        </History>
    </Class>
    <Class>
        <History>
            <StudentName>Rebecca</StudentName>
        </History>
    </Class>
</College>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<College>
   <Class>
      <History>
         <StudentName>Veronica</StudentName>
      </History>
   </Class>
   <Class>
      <History>
         <StudentName>Jasmine</StudentName>
      </History>
   </Class>
   <Class>
      <History>
         <StudentName>Rebecca</StudentName>
      </History>
      <AddThis>Ok</AddThis>
   </Class>
</College>
```

**Explanation**: Very typical overriding of the identity rule.

**XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pNum" select="3"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Class[History][position() = $pNum]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      <AddThis>Ok</AddThis>
    </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Explanation**: Almost the same as the XSLT 1.0 solution, but shorter, because in XSLT 2.0 it is legal for a variable/parameter reference to occur in a match pattern -- therefore we get rid completely of the explicit conditionals.

**Update**: The OP has now modified the problem:

> "*sorry, the "AddThis" element was suppose to be added inside the
>   third "History" node, not outside the third "History" node, my bad. I
>   corrected this in my question post. How would I edit your XSLT 1.0 to
>   correct this? Thanks. – Bug Spray*"

**Here is the correspondingly modified solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pNum" select="3"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Class[History]">
  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="not(position() = $pNum)">
     <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="add"/>
   </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="add" name="id2">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="add"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="History/StudentName" mode="add">
  <xsl:call-template name="id2"/>
  <AddThis>Ok</AddThis>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your condition is never satisfied because `preceding-sibling::` does what it says on the tin: it selects preceding *sibling* nodes. Of which there won't be any in your XML structure for the `History` elements! So your test attribute will always yield an expression equivalent to: `test="(0 +1) = 3"`, i.e `test="false()"`.

You will need to either rethink your XPath selector i.e you need to select the `preceding-sibling::` nodes on the `parent::` node; *or* you need to restructure your XSLT so that the flow of template matching automatically selects the nodes properly. (Something like `match="Class[(position() +1)= $position]"` to select the 4th position in your example.)

Additionally, your logic is odd: XSLT indices/positions are 1-based and not 0-based as with most languages. Therefore it seems clearer to select the 4th element by modifying your `$position` param clause, rather than by adding it inside a subexpression of your predicate.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my errors.  I corrected my XSLT 1.0 and it now works with these changes, I changed the original test clause to this <xsl:if test="(count(preceding-sibling::Class) + 1) = $nodeNumber">